# Wordpress: Creating a thorough custom post type for recipes

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I am currently trying to create a custom post type for recipes. My goal is to include the schema.org/Recipe and or hrecipe microformat and also have the ability to filter for ingredients in the future.

To do this I intend to have an interface with fields for title, photo, description, ingredients and instructions.

My question is: Should I create separate fields for each ingredient and each amount? Or would you say it is sufficient to just create one field for all ingredients? (also keeping the aforementioned microformats in mind).

http://schema.org/Recipe

http://microformats.org/wiki/hrecipe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having ingredients as a single field is what is expected in both formats you linked to. Querying / filtering based on ingredient name will be slightly more complex...but you should be able to handle it.

There are 3 parts to this answer.

1. How should you save ingredients in WordPress
2. How should you allow users to modify the ingredients list
3. How should you display ingredients publicly

For point 1, you will have to give a bit of thought as to how you save the ingredient list and how you retrieve/display it along with how it is queried.  One of the formats indicate you could have properties for each ingredient (still in draft).

You could save an ingredient list as a serialized PHP array, something like this:

$ingredients[]=array('milk','value'=>'125','type'=>'ml');
$ingredients[]=array('sugar','value'=>'1','type'=>'cup');

Since serialized PHP arrays are standardized, you could fairly easily write an WP query that takes it into account.

Keep in mind you will want to have a plan for when the 'value' and 'type' modifiers are set in stone and how to migrate what you saved if they are different.

For point 2, you could create a custom meta box that deserializes the PHP array saved and render individual controls for each ingredient along with controls to allow management (Add, Deletes, Updates).

For point 3....the easiest would be to get the value and manipulate it how you want in the output.

Comment: Thank you. I just realized that I probably lack the competence to do this myself (at least efficiently). Getting a theme together was one thing. This is a different one. I will probably pay someone to do it.

Comment: By the way, I seem to misunderstand either you or the formats: The way I see it, both formats expect every single ingredient to be in some way separated from the others. I understand you imply that this _requires_ them to be in a _single_ field?